# What happens when i use inline style and css files in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stylesheet

I am refering to a situation in which i have something like this:

```
import "./myCss.css"
const BeautyButton = (props) =>{
    return (
        <a style={{backgroundColor:"red"}} className="blue-background" >hello</a>
    );
}
```

Which property prevails? Is there a general rule for all the properties (fontSize, width, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing different between how CSS works in React and with regular HTML. To understand which rules take effect, you'll want to study the concept of [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in CSS.

For your specific question, inline styles are considered more specific than styles in external stylesheets, so those styles will prevail.